# NetLogo - Behavior Space - controlling variable value

Tags: netlogo

I am having a problem in working on Behavior Space. I have 3 parameters, percentage A, Percentage B and Percentage C. I want to vary values of these three in behavior space experiment but the sum of it must be always 100. For example, Percentage A 30%, Percentage B 30%, Percentage C 40%.

```
["percentage A" 50]

["percentage B" 25]

["percentage C" 25]
```

Comment: What is your specific question and what programming language are you using ?

Comment: I am using netlogo, software for agent based modeling. There is tool named Behavior space, it helps to create experiment by varying values of parameters. These 3 types Percentage A, B and C are some of my parameters and I want to vary these 3 but also I want to keep the sum of every variation is always 100. I haven't found the way to do that.

Comment: Great - thanks for adding a `netlogo` tag - I've also removed some inappropriate tags and cleaned up the title. Hopefully the question will be clearer now.

Comment: thank you for questioning, I forgot to add it.

Comment: BehaviorSpace will vary each parameter independently.  If the sum is constrained, you cannot sensibly vary all three independently.  Instead, your model can pick two parameters for the interface, and your `setup` can compute the third.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to skip unsufficient parameter settings would be the use of a stop condition. In the variables section of "Behaviour space" you can vary your parameters automatically by a range definition like:

```
["percentageA" [0 10 100]]
["percentageB" [0 10 100]]
["percentageC" [0 10 100]]
```

This would of course generate combinations which do not have a sum of 100. 
Next in the reporter section you could add a reporter, which helps to filter your results later on:

```
(percentageA + percentageB + percentageC)
```

In the bottom section of the Behaviour Space Menu you can then simply add a stop condition like:

```
(percentageA + percentageB + percentageC != 100)
```

This condition will skip all unsufficient variations. Nevertheless you still would have entries in the output file for runs with unsufficient combinations but you can easily filter them. Just use the defined reporter and select only those entries with a value of 100 in that column.

Comment: Nice solution, Tyr.  I had a similar problem, and ended up just using a few separate Behavior Space specifications.